# How do I select a blocked chart in a Excel 2010 chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

How can I select a blocked or protected chart in Excel 2010?

When I right-click on the chart, the cursor changes to a circle with a diagonal line within it - a "blocked" sign. I'm doing a study assignment and only want to copy the chart into a PPT file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlock sheet by password, there is no way to copy from a protected sheet.

To capture the screen then pick the chart might be a possible solution for you.